# I want to specific images and copy it

Tags: python

```
from shutil import copyfile
import os 

src = r'E:\DCIM phone\9-1-2020\DCIM\Screenshots'
dst = r'E:\New folder'

for f_name in os.listdir(r'E:\DCIM phone\9-1-2020\DCIM\Screenshots'):
    if f_name.endswith('chrome'):
        copyfile(src, dst)
```

why it's not working although it doesn't raise error
I want to select images and copy it....

Comment: You have to copy src + f_name, not src.

Comment: It seems unlikely that your image file names actually end in "chrome" - there's probably an extension such as ".png" or ".jpeg".  Windows might hide the extension by default, but as a programmer you cannot ignore them.

Comment: Are you sure there are files that end with "chrome"? I would assume they end with ".jpeg" or ".jpg". Hence my `if` statement will be like `if f_name.contains("chrome"):` And yes, you need to add `src + f_name`

Comment: Windows as default display filenames without extensions `.jpg`, `.png` but you have to use them in code - `endswith( ("chrome.jpg", "chrome.jpeg", "chrome.JPG", "chrome.JPEG") )`

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems in your code.

**First:** Windows as default display some filenames with extensions but you have to use filenames with extensions.

```
if filename.endswith( ('chrome.jpg', 'chrome.JPG', 'chrome.png', 'chrome.PNG') ):
```

or with `lower()`

```
if filename.lower().endswith( ('chrome.jpg', 'chrome.png') ):
```

Eventually check in any place inside filename

```
if 'chrome' in filename.lower():
```

You can also use both

```
if ('chrome' in filename.lower()) and filename.lower().endswith( ('.jpg', '.png') ):
```

**Second:** `listdir()` gives only `filename` but you need `src/filename` and `dst/filename`

```
full_src = os.path.join(src, filename)
full_dst = os.path.join(dst, filename)

copyfile(full_src, full_dst)
```

---

Code:

```
import os 
from shutil import copyfile

src = r'E:\DCIM phone\9-1-2020\DCIM\Screenshots'
dst = r'E:\New folder'

for filename in os.listdir(src):
    if filename.lower().endswith( ('chrome.jpg', 'chrome.png') ):
        full_scr = os.path.join(src, filename)
        full_dst = os.path.join(dst, filename)
        copyfile(full_scr, full_dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

add filename to src,

```
from shutil import copyfile
import os 

src = r'E:\DCIM phone\9-1-2020\DCIM\Screenshots'
dst = r'E:\New folder'

for f_name in os.listdir(r'E:\DCIM phone\9-1-2020\DCIM\Screenshots'):
    if f_name.endswith('chrome'):
        src = src + '\' + fname
        copyfile(src, dst)
```